# Two views referencing each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have two textviews declared as below. My intention is to have two views side by side, where left view (displaying user name) has bigger text size, right view displays time of last message send and should be always visible (even if user has really long name, that's why I'm using android:layout_toLeftOf). However, left view is smaller and I want to align its baseline to right view. It's really nice dependency where and I'm not able to solve it.

Partially acceptable solution is to use "android:layout_toRightOf" in right view, but if user has really long name, then time (right view) will be ellipsized (it's declared in AppTheme.TextView.SingleLine).

So basically, my questions is, is it possible for two views to reference each other? I understand why I'm getting this error, but I'm not able to solve it.
I remember from my C/C++ times that it was possible to declare function in the top of the file and then define it somewhere else (so the compiler doesn't complain) and I think it's something what I need here.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_messages_item_sender_name"
        style="@style/AppTheme.TextView.SingleLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fragment_messages_item_last_msg_time"
        android:textSize="@dimen/global_text_large"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_messages_item_last_msg_time"
        style="@style/AppTheme.TextView.SingleLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/fragment_messages_item_sender_name"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="right"/>
```

All I'm getting is

```
Error:(27, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toLeftOf' with value '@id/fragment_messages_item_last_msg_time').
```

Comment: You can't make two views refer each other. What is the purpose to do that?

Comment: @intrepidkarthi please see my comment to blackbelt's answer and you'll see why I need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could move the `android:layout_alignBaseline` in the other `TextView`. Be aware of id loops, that usually generated nasty crashes.

About your issue, you have to remember the entries inside R are marked as  `public static final`, and that the `+` generates a new entry for the specify id, if it does not exists, So you can have:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment_messages_item_last_msg_time"
```

in the first `TextView`, and

```
android:id="@id/fragment_messages_item_last_msg_time"
```

to the second one. As I mentioned before, loops in RelativeLayout are not allowed, and those  will make your app crash

Comment: Thank you for answer! You're right about +id/ id/ and I actually wasn't aware of this difference. However, I still need to user android:layout_alignBaseline in my right view, as it has smaller text and I want to align smaller text to baseline of larger text (left view), not the other way

Comment: I see, of course I don't know the constrains of you application, just be aware that loops in relative layout can make your app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

in R class id like

```
fragment_messages_item_last_msg_time
```

not exist
for avoid that problem need to use "+" before declaration field with id relation

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="+@id/fragment_messages_item_last_msg_time"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Hi use below code :    

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_messages_item_sender_name"
            style="@style/AppTheme.TextView.SingleLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Manish" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_messages_item_last_msg_time"
            style="@style/AppTheme.TextView.SingleLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Khamar" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes, you're also right and this can be also done using linear layout's weight attribute, but my relative layout contains other views I'm not showing in snippet, so I need to use relative layout instead of linear layout. Thanks anyway!